# Forcing 'yes' to new update license agreements?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, software-installation

Sometimes when a new version of a big piece of software is released (java, flash, etc), the developers will require that a license agreement be combed through and then ask you to type (yes/no) at the end.

Is there a way of forcing my package manager to accept the agreement?

I'm using zypper on OpenSuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `zypper` the `--auto-agree-with-licenses` flag. From the [OpenSUSE wiki](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aZypper_usage_11.3#Auto-agree_with_licenses):

> This is special option for the install, remove and update commands. By using this, the user declares he/she agrees with the terms of licenses the command will install, and zypper will automatically say 'yes' to the license confirmation prompt. This is useful for people installing the same set of packages on multiple machines (by an automated process) and have read all the licenses before.

Comment: I guess I should have RTFM :) Thanks for this. Hopefully it will help someone else.